# docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint web :Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker and learning from here: https://www.lynda.com/Docker-tutorials/Run-container-ports-volumes/576584/604557-4.html?org=mastercard.com

I already went through the link and reponse seem confusing : https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3277

Error:

```
docker container run -d --name web -p 8080:8080 jboss/wildfly
4f75dcbf8a56262a22239b5ef146a475f7d877a1707392561bb9419542510478
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint web (645121a4674ed37eaeefb46c2afcff6512477dba4dd98f93d4f8f5e40750f111): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use.

$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep 8080
    tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      2527/dockerd
```

The part ***8080/tcp*** is confusing to me and not sure why it's coming.

```
docker container ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
c65137b42e56        jboss/wildfly       "/opt/jboss/wildfl..."   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp   web
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on mac try

```
docker container run -d --name web -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 jboss/wildfly
```

Good Luck

Daniel Farina